# Custom Journey Builder Activity not getting triggered

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

Custom activity in Journey Builder requests doesn't reach backend server where custom activity code reside ( i.e execute endpoint doesn't trigger when journey is activated)

I am facing this issue since long time and its very critical and we need solution to resolve it

Kindly help & provide me solution.

Comment: We can't help you diagnose this issue without seeing your activity configuration. Can you post the relevant information here?

Comment: @JasonHanshaw  - I have attached the relevant documents in this links  [link](https://spaces.hightail.com/receive/kxRbpZFaVh). Could you please go through it and I hope you get clear understanding of custom activity configuration

Comment: @JasonHanshaw - Please check the link and help with some solution